# Python Selenium Page scrolling and clicking next button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone have any python code that would allow me to scroll from top to the bottom of a page and then click on a button to load more pages in the browser?

Comment: Thank you for the information. When the process scrolls through all the links by hitting the button multiple times and loads all of the data the process ends and times out. Why is this I had tagged on the bottom of the code; except NoSuchElementException:break

Answer (score 1):

To scroll to the bottom of the page you can use:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

To click on a button you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button.c_button.s_button').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. When the process scrolls through all the links by hitting the button multiple times and loads all of the data the process ends and times out. Why is this I had tagged on the bottom of the code; except NoSuchElementException:break

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can use JS

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to scroll page down to the bottom:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Or if you want to scroll down to exact button to be able to click it:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Next"]') # Selector might differs
button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
button.click()
```