# Python Selenium - Click Button

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following anchor tag at the bottom of a page. I want to be able to scroll down the web page then click the button at the bottom to constantly load all the data then finish. Would you know what I need to classify in order for the process to work?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: block;" role="button" class="btn btn-accordion search js-accordion-trigger xh-highlight">View More Professionals</a>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: block;" role="button" class="btn btn-accordion search js-accordion-trigger xh-highlight">View More Professionals</a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Page scrolling and clicking next button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558528/python-selenium-page-scrolling-and-clicking-next-button)

Comment: You should add more details to your previous ticket instead of submitting new one with the same issue